# where is the port-forward rule file stored in vscode?

Tags: portforwarding, vscode-remote

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkLMn.png)
every time we open vscode，and use remote-ssh to link remote server, the port-forward info is diffrent？the port of localhost:xxx is changing every time...

we want to persist store port-forward rule in local db, trying to have a same port-forward rule whenever open vscode。 so，if somebody knows where is the port-forward rule file？
please tell me, we need your help
we want to persist store port-forward rule in local db, trying to have a same port-forward rule whenever open vscode。 so，if somebody knows where is the port-forward rule file？
please tell me, we need your help